# Use multiple components in Flash AS3 - iPhone app

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3

*First of all: Happy new year!*

I have a problem with Flash CS5.5, AS3. I have two ScrollPane Components in my document. They are both in another scene and the (instant)names are unique. But it isn’t working properly. When I go to the other scene with the second ScrollPane I get an error & it starts to flicker.

My error:

> TypeError: Error #1006: setSize is not a function. at
>   application051_fla::MainTimeline/frame25()[application051_fla.MainTimeline::frame25:7]

I want to make an iPhone application and I want that multiple components working properly in one document.

My little piece of code (don’t think that the problem is in here):

```
ScrollPane02.source = tekst03;
ScrollPane02.setSize(350,400);
ScrollPane02.move(0, 20);
ScrollPane02.scrollDrag = false;
```

If you know the answer or what I am doing wrong, please comment! Searching for hours/days!

Thanks in advance!

- Uploaded the .fla document. If you want to take a look at it (please), you can download it here: http://www.bregjebouwmans.nl/application061.fla

Comment: Based on your info alone this should work. It could have to do with multiple things. Could you give more info of the contents of your Scenes or maybe even upload the fla?

Comment: Hi @rvmook I am going to upload the file. Thanks already!

Comment: @bregina: the problem could lie in the fact that you created ScrollPane02 as a library symbol. You can use the same symbol as the one in the first frame and change its name in the properties panel.

Comment: I don't have CS5.5 myself (I have CS4). So I can't open your fla. Hopefully @AsTheWormTurns suggestion can help you out.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns, could you be more specific, please? 'Cause if I change it I immediately get an error. I am really a newbie. Thank you for taking a look at it! (like your name by the way!)

Comment: @bregina: I posted a link to a modified version of your file, you could download it and try if it works as expected

Comment: @rvmook, too bad I can't figure it out. Saved it also as a cs4 document. If you have a bit more time, please download it: [link]http://www.bregjebouwmans.nl/application062_cs4.fla

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns, where can I find that file? Also new here.. omg!

Comment: @bregina: http://www.mediafire.com/?ytxipa8g23azz2p (wait, then click the green button)

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns, You are really a life saver! What did you do different.. You ues the same component from the library?
Now I get another error, but it is working how I wanted to be... Super thanks!

Comment: @bregina: I simply deleted the second component from your library, copied the one you had in the first frame to the second and renamed it to 'ScrollPane02'. You don't have to create different components in the library: you can have many instances of the same component with different instance names (->property panel). I don't get any other error here (maybe your error is not related to the very little change I made).

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns, excellent! Can I help you to rate something? 'Cause this is really helping me. Now I can go on with my life and finish the damn thing. Prob getting more dragons to slay but I see them when I have to face them! THANK YOU, A LOT!!

Comment: @bregina: don't worry, I really don't care about ratings.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Ok, after digging through the FLA, I finally figured out what you did . . . you right clicked on `ScrollPane` in the "Library", and clicked "Duplicate".  Then you gave it the name `ScrollPane02`.  Except that the duplication process did not connect the new object to the `ScrollPane`'s setup.  Instead, it created a generic `MovieClip` object.  Since it is not an actual `ScrollPane`, it makes sense that all the methods on the timeline's Actionscript will fail.

This is why the solution (in the comments below) works.  @AsTheWormTurns just used the first (actual) `ScrollPane` in two instances on the timeline; is a viable solution.

(The only caveat being that if you change the `ScrollPane` object in the Library, it will affect all instances.  That shouldn't really be a problem, since -- for components -- you generally make changes only to instances.)

---

Useful tips from my initial answer:

When compiled into an SWF, scenes are just stuck one right after the other in the timeline, just like scenes in a movie.  If you do not have a `stop()` at the end of one scene, it will continue to run right into the next scene, just like a movie.  The idea of scenes is to separate content.  This means that what exists in sceneA does not exist in sceneB.  The scenes also have no access to each other.

My advice is to not use scenes at all.  They are difficult to use correctly, and have very little use that is not better done using the timeline or Actionscript.

Comment: I have a 'stop();' in every scene. That's working just fine. I could all put all the content in the timeline and remove the scene's. But in every new scene I have new components and it's own code. So this shouldn't be a problem.

Still don't get it. Thank you for your quick response. I will try to upload the file & I'm going to work with a timeline.

Comment: The reason why it's flickering is becasue of the error. Flash coudn't interpret the Actionscript correctly and therefore ignores it.

Comment: Thnx for another quick response, @rvmook! I understand that Flash can't read my actionscript or at least that it isn't working correctly right now. Otherwise I wouldn't get the error. If you have a bit of time. Please download my ,fla file. It is seriously driving me crazy. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns That's a good solution -- using the same ScrollPane from the library.  You should probably put that as an (correct) answer, with a bit of an explanation.  bregina, as long as you make changes to the individual ScrollPanes in Actionscript (changes to the library ScrollPane will affect all instances), this will work fine.